# How to create a sub directory inside a private directory in android

Tags: android, android-file

I have created a directory like this:

```
File mydir = context.getDir("my_private_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now I want to create another directory inside `my_private_dir`for which I've tried doing it this way:

```
 File file = new File(mydir.getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + date);
            if (file.mkdir())
                Log.d(context.getClass().getSimpleName()," date dir created");
```

I don't know why this is not working out. The subdirectory is not getting created at all.

I want all the directories to be private and only my app should be able to access it. SO I thought to make the parent directory private and to create subdirectories inside it normally will be enough. But I'm not able to understand why the subdirectory is not getting created.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Regards

Comment: "I've tried doing it this way" -- use `new File(mydir.getAbsolutePath(), date)`. "The subdirectory is not getting created at all" -- how **exactly** are you determining this? "I want all the directories to be private and only my app should be able to access it" -- everything on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is private, which includes `getDir()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use mkdirs() instead of mkdir()

```
 File file = new File(mydir.getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + date);
        if (file.mkdirs())
            Log.d(context.getClass().getSimpleName()," date dir created");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man that helped me create a subdirectory. But Can you please help me understand why mkdirs() and why not mkdir()?